# Mockito when isn't replacing original method behaviour

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I got 2 modules `User` and `Email`, both of them have 1 entry point which is a facade, rest is package scoped. The configuration is done in 2 classes

```
@Configuration
class UserConfiguration {
    @Bean
    UserFacade userFacade(UserRepository repository, EmailFacade emailFacade) {
        return new UserFacade(repository, emailFacade);
    }
}

@Configuration
class EmailConfiguration {
    @Bean
    EmailFacade emailFacade(EmailSender emailSender) {
        return new EmailFacade(emailSender);
    }
}
```

[image]

Now, I want to write tests that don't require Spring to start. I implemented a simple `InMemoryRepository` to make this happen

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RegisterUserTest {
    @Mock
    private EmailFacade emailFacade = new EmailFacade(new FakeEmailSender());

    @InjectMocks
    private UserFacade userFacade = new UserConfiguration().userFacade(new InMemoryUserRepository(), emailFacade);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

I need some fake objects to instantiate `EmailFacade` so I wrote fake implementation

```
public class FakeEmailSender implements EmailSender {
    @Override
    public void sendEmail(EmailMessage emailMessage) throws RuntimeException {

    }
}
```

In that scenario, I'm testing `User` domain, so I want to mock `Email` anyways.

I wrote a test to check if it works

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnSendingFailed() {
    Mockito.when(emailFacade.sendUserVerificationEmail(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Either.left(EmailError.SENDING_FAILED));      
    assertThat(userFacade.registerNewUser(RegisterUserDto.builder()
            .username(USERNAME_4)
            .email(VALID_EMAIL)
            .password(VALID_PASSWORD).build()).getLeft(), is(EmailError.SENDING_FAILED));
}
```

But it isn't... after running this test I got

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: getLeft() on Right

edit#

`regiserNewUser()` method

```
 Either<DomainError, SuccessMessage> register(RegisterUserDto registerUserDto) {
        if(userRepository.findUser(registerUserDto.getUsername()).isPresent())
            return Either.left(UserError.USERNAME_ALREADY_EXISTS);
        var userCreationResult = User.createUser(registerUserDto);
        var savedUser = userCreationResult.map(this::saveUser);
        var emailDto = savedUser.map(this::createVerificationEmail);
        return emailDto.isRight() ? emailFacade.sendUserVerificationEmail(emailDto.get())
                : Either.left(emailDto.getLeft());
    }
```

Edit2#
With following test configuration

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RegisterUserTest {
    @Mock
    private EmailFacade emailFacade;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserFacade userFacade = new UserConfiguration().userFacade(new InMemoryUserRepository(), emailFacade);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

I got nullpointer here, last line of `registerNewUser()`.
[image]

Comment: You might want to add the `registerNewUser` method to your question.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write `@Mock private EmailFacade emailFacade = new EmailFacade(new FakeEmailSender());`.  Either you want this to be a mock, or you want it to be `new EmailFacade(new FakeEmailSender())`.  It can't be both.

Comment: Added `registerNewUser()` method. So if I want to mock I should just write `@Mock
 private EmailFacade emailFacade;`? But then Im getting nullpointers while calling this in `registerNewUser()` method...

Comment: What particular line is giving you the null pointer exception?

Comment: `return emailDto.isRight() ? emailFacade.sendUserVerificationEmail(emailDto.get())
                : Either.left(emailDto.getLeft());` - calling `emailFacade` which should be mocked and return `Either.left()`

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace as well? Does the exception come from `emailDto.getLeft()` in which case we would need to know more about what `savedUser.map(this::createVerificationEmail);` is doing. Or does it come `registerNewUser(...).getLeft()` ?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: While the current initialisation of the mocks might not make much sense, he ends up with a `mock` for `EmailFacade` anyway. So lets focus on one problem at a time. @Weeedooo: You might want to open a new question for the `NullPointerException` (and include the adjusted code and the stacktrace over there).

Comment: And did you step through with the debugger to find which expression was null on that line?

Comment: Yes I did, it looks like whole `emailFacade` is null at that point. I'v added image to question. I'm confused tho, I'm don't want to use spring for tests, but I'm expecting `EmailFacade` to be injected into my test? Or `@Mock` isn't working like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RegisterUserTest {
    @Mock
    private EmailFacade emailFacade;

    private UserFacade userFacade;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        userFacade = new UserConfiguration().userFacade(new InMemoryUserRepository(), emailFacade);
    }
}
```

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You initialize your mocks twice. You don’t need to call initMocks in the setUp method if you are using Mockito runner
2. You are trying to inject mocks to already initialized object. But the field you are trying to inject is also passed to the constructor. Please read [@InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) doc, to check the strategies used to inject the mocks:

   - constructor (not used here, already initialized object)
   - setter (do you have one?)
   - field (is it not final)

There are details to each strategy (see my questions above). If no staregy is matched, Mockito will fail silently. The fact that you are passing an object in constructor, and rely on setter or field injection afterwards makes this code unnecesarily complex.